# Trying to inject an @Client in to a Groovy Function

Tags: groovy, aws-lambda, micronaut

I'm trying to write a Micronaut AWS Groovy Lambda which makes HTTPS calls out to another service. I have followed the MN Docs and have created my project using:

```
 mn create-function hello-world -lang groovy
```

This gave me a skeleton "hello-world" project with a functional test that I can run.

I then tried to modify the Groovy function (`hello.world.HelloWorldFunction`) to inject an HTTP client with the intention of calling the API within my function:

```
import static io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest.GET

@Field @Inject @Client("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1") RxHttpClient httpClient

Maybe<String> helloWorld() {
    httpClient.retrieve(GET("/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699"))
              .firstElement()

}
```

Having done this I now get an exception when I run the functional test:

```
08:51:25.269 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] ERROR 
i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: 
Failed to inject value for field [httpClient] of class: 
hello.world.HelloWorldFunction

Path Taken: HelloWorldFunction.httpClient
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for field [httpClient] of class: 
hello.world.HelloWorldFunction

Path Taken: HelloWorldFunction.httpClient
```

I'm almost certainly doing something wrong, but I'm at a bit of a loss in terms of how to figure out what. Hence grateful for any pointers.

Many thanks,

Edd

Comment: Can you post all your `import` statements ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this. It's a bug in `1.0.0.M1`. It's already fixed in master though so can be worked around by building Micronaut from source and using that.

In addition I discovered that I was returning a type that is unsupported by Lambda functions (`Maybe<String>`). After building MN from master and changing this to a supported return type everything is now working.